# ArcGIS for Desktop equivalents to ArcInfo Workstation tolerance types?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcinfo-workstation

In ArcInfo Workstation (formerly called ARC/INFO), the ARC: command TOLERANCE was used to specify fuzzy, grain, weed, snap and nodesnap as the types of tolerances for coverages.

When creating a feature class, what would be the equivalent of these?

There do not seem to be any options to specify these in ArcGIS for Desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think of **[Fuzzy Tolerance](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/GISDictionary/term/fuzzy%20tolerance)** from ArcInfo Workstation as being more or less equivalent to **[Cluster Tolerance](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/GISDictionary/term/cluster%20tolerance)** from ArcGIS for Desktop.  The other tolerances were there for generalising (grain/weed) and snapping (snap/nodesnap).

To achieve the equivalent of DOUBLE PRECISION from ARC/INFO my understanding is that you can just accept all the defaults from the last panel of the wizard for Create Feature Class.

Comment: Thanks. Thats pretty much what I've come to conclude from testing and comparing the tabular results of both formats.

Answer (score 1):

The [XY Tolerance](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n0000001v000000) is part of the spatial reference of a feature class. This is the equivalent of the fuzzy and snap tolerance values you can set for a coverage, although they cannot be different in ArcGIS.

There is also a geoprocessing environment setting: [XY Tolerance](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w0000000r000000) that will override any settings from the inputs to a geoprocessing tool that recognizes the setting.

The defaults in the geodatabase (in most situations) will give you an XY resolution that far exceeds double-precision floating point!